# Is there a supported Windows CIM/WMI provider for Dell PERC Generation 11 or later?

Tags: powershell, dell-poweredge, wmi, dell-perc

I have [Dell OpenManage Server Administrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenManage#OMSA_.E2.80.93_OpenManage_Server_Administrator) (version 7.4) for Windows installed on a [12th generation server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dell_PowerEdge_Servers#Generation_12) with a PERC H710P.  That machine has a [`root\cimv2\dell` namespace](https://gist.github.com/alx9r/4674154022e12598289f) which does not seem to include any mention of disks or disk controllers (although that namespace contains other useful things).

These are the closest things I've found to a Windows CIM provider for PERC:

- [a Dell-supported CIM provider for ESXi](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/b/techcenter/archive/2013/07/01/monitoring-dell-poweredge-raid-controllers-in-vmware-esxi)
- [discussions about using LSI MegaCLI on Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/388144/115232)
- [Dell KB using MegaCLI on Windows](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN292232?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04).

I haven't, however, found any reference to a Dell-supported CIM provider for PERC for Windows.

`omreport storage` and `omconfig storage` seems to be the only scriptable Dell-supported API.  The [Dell OMSA User's guide](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/dell-opnmang-srvr-admin-v7.4_User's%20Guide6_en-us.pdf) indicates that output from OMSA is a character stream.  The guide provides some information about the contents of that stream but there is no specification that facilitates *reliable* parsing of the output.

1. Is there a supported Windows CIM/WMI provider for Dell PERC Generation 11 or later?
2. Is there some other supported method of managing or at least querying PERC from Powershell that doesn't involving parsing an undefined string?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there a supported Windows CIM/WMI provider for Dell PERC Generation 11 or later?

I haven't found one.  It looks like the `omreport storage` and `omconfig storage` are the supported scriptable interfaces to PERC.

> 2. Is there some other supported method of managing or at least querying PERC from Powershell that doesn't involving parsing an undefined string?

I haven't found one.  I ended up writing [this PowerShell module](https://github.com/alx9r/PsOmsa) that implements the arcane parsing of the output from `omreport storage`.  Using the `-fmt ssv` switch made the output of `omreport storage` a bit easier to parse.